# How to rebuild project from Framework version 2.0 to version 1.1?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-1.1

I created app for Framework 2.0, but suddenly get know, that i need to make it on Framework 1.1. I tried to rebuild my project on required version Framework as i did it before(from 4.0 to 2.0), but unfortunatelly visual studio 2015 update 1 haven't got such version at the list to choose. Is it ever possible to rebuild it somehow? I googled it, but didn't find anything.

Comment: This isn't rebuilding, it's backporting, if not rewriting from scratch. 2.0 introduced a  **LOT** of fundamental differences, for example, generics. There were no `List<t>` or `Dictionary<K,V>` in 1.1. Anyway, do you realize that .NET 1.1 support ended a decade ago? It's *not* supported on Windows 7 (the oldest supported Windows version). The last Visual Studio version to support 1.1 was 2008 (maybe)

Comment: To put it another way, where will you find an OS that can run .NET 1.1? In fact, even 2.0 is out of support. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2

Comment: From what I remember, when working with windows server 2003 it already had net 2.0, so 1.1 is really old. @Ramon can you explain why you actually need it in version 1.1? Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for answer. Yes, i understand it, but we can work only with Framework 1.1 because of technical reasons. Do you know maybe some web pages where describe what features from 2.0 where changed or added since 1.0 version ?

Comment: @arieljannai    I exactly working now with virtual machine with windows server 2003 service pack 1, and unfortunatelly there's no 2.0, only 1.1, that's the point :( My boss prohibited to install newer version of Framework, because of some technical reasons. We also thought that windows server had a 2.0 version, odd but it has only 1.1 :/

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos windows server 2003 can run .NET 1, and for this OS i exactly made a project.

Comment: Technical reasons are the reasons why you *can't* work with .NET 1.1 - it's not supported as in it won't run. Visual Studio stopped supporting it 7 years ago. Technical reasons explain why you *can't* use Windows Server 2003 any more. I won't speculate on the type of reasons that force the selection of an abandonded OS except - where will you get *legal* licenses to run this? You can't buy 2003 licenses any more.

Comment: @Ramon if you insist, just find an old *legal* copy of Visual Studio 2008. You may be able to get it if you have an MSDN subscription. It's not available for sale any more

Comment: @Ramon I'd suggest you make *absolutely* certain that your customers will use Windows XP or 2003. It would be a waste of ... time at least, if you found out that their machines run modern OSs simply because they can't find any Windows XP machines or licenses.

Comment: [You can only download vs2003 if you have an msdb subscription](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c2286b91-096b-4f36-9880-69ac3fa7d309/download-visual-studio-2003?forum=vssetup). And I also really advise you to take @PanagiotisKanavos advice and check if you really must use it. You might encounter a lot of problems later when trying to support it.

Comment: The MSDN subscriptions [start at $1200](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/) and include Visual Studio Pro

Comment: @arieljannai Thanks guys for advises and for your time! I'll try to convince my boss to use more newer version of Framework, cause you right, i absolutelly agree with you, it's old, and it pointless to develop on it. Thanks again!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks guys for advises and for your time! I'll try to convince my boss to use more newer version of Framework, cause you right, i absolutelly agree with you, it's old, and it pointless to develop on it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2003 is the last version to support .NET 1.1. So you'll need to port it back to that version. Depending on what you used in the framework, there can be a lot of breaking changes when backporting. Unfortunately, the release notes only describe the breaking changes when going from 1.1 **to** 2.0, not the other way around.

**But** I highly recommend not to do so. .NET 1.1 is **old** and it's no longer supported, neither is Visual Studio 2003:

> .NET Framework 1.1 SP1: The .NET Framework 1.0 was supported at the latest Service Pack level (SP1) under an individual product lifecycle policy until October 8, 2013. However, .NET Framework 1.1 SP1 will continue to be supported until end of support of Windows Server 2003 SP2 (with 32-bit only, not 64-bit).
>
> Note that the extension does not apply to Windows Server 2003 SP2 64-bit edition and Windows Server 2003 Itanium based systems where .NET Framework 1.1 did not ship as a component in the operating system.

<sup>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/framework_faq/en-us</sup>

> Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 Service Pack 1
>
> Lifecycle Start Date  Mainstream Support End Date
>
> 9/15/2006                  10/14/2008                10/8/2013

<sup>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20.NET%202003%20Service%20Pack%201</sup>

Comment: *Generics* are enough to make backporting a nightmare. For each `List<T>`, the OP would have to *hand-code* a class that implements a list for a specific type. Or use casts from Object everywhere, hoping there won't be an InvalidCastException because the wrong object was added to the list

Comment: Agreed. Generics and the use of .NET 2.0 specific Windows Forms or ASP.NET controls are a very likely breaking change. I'd personally ship the .NET 2.0 framework and SP3 with the app, if it were me.